# Change function name in a .so library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I only have 1 .so file from old project.
How can I use this file without creating the same package in project or module ?

Comment: You might be able to change it using a hex editor or some similar tool. But it seems much easier to just create a package with the same name within your new project.

Comment: Hi @Michael I tried using notepad ++ to edit the hex text of the file compared to another package (I changed 1 word for test) but there was an error: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com void ...."

Comment: That's not enough information. You should show exactly what you changed, and the full exact error messages that you get.

Comment: @Michael Example old package of so file is: "com.abc.def" I find in hex editor to change "f" to "e" then package change to "com.abc.dee". Messenges show "No implementation found for void com.abc.dee.Native.appInit(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, boolean) (tried Java_com_abc_dee_Native_appInit and Java_com_abc_dee_Native_appInit__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2IZ)"

Comment: Not only the method name, but the method signature need to match exactly with the one inside .so. Also, you need to change all the occurrences of that JNI method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to change function name in `.so` file. You can use [`dlopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to load your `.so` library dynamically at runtime and [`dlsym`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to get pointer for you `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME()` and then call `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME()` by pointer. For do that in your current project you can create "wrapper" like that:

```
public class OldSoHelper {
    public static native void loadOldSo();
    public static native <TYPE_OF_RESULT> runFunFromOldSo(<PARAMETERS>);
    public static native void unloadOldSo();
}
```

and in corresponding `.c/.cpp` file of current project (e.g. `native-lib.cpp` by default):

```
void *handle;
<TYPE_OF_OLD_FUNCTION> (*old_fun_wrapper)(<PARAMETERS_OF_OLD_FUNCTION>);

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>_OldSoHelper_loadOldSo(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
     handle = dlopen("<YOUR_OLD_SO>.so", RTLD_NOW);
     old_fun_wrapper = (<TYPE_OF_OLD_FUNCTION> (*)(<PARAMETERS_OF_OLD_FUNCTION>))(dlsym(handle, "<OLD_FUNCTION_NAME_e.g._Java_com_abc_dee_Native_appInit>"));
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>_OldSoHelper_runFunFromOldSo(JNIEnv *env, jclass type,
                                                      <PARAMETERS_FOR_OLD_FUNCTION>)
{   
    jclass ResultClass = env->FindClass("YOUR/PACKAGE/NAME/RESULT_CLASS");
    jobject result = ...
    jfieldID fieldId = env->GetFieldID(ResultClass, "<FIELD_NAME>", "<FILED_TYPE_LETTER>");

    <TYPE_OF_OLD_FUNCTION> res = old_fun_wrapper(<PARAMETERS_FOR_OLD_FUNCTION>);

    env->Set<TYPE>Field(result, fieldId , res.filed);

    return result;
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>_OldSoHelper_unloadOldSo(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
     if (handle) {
         dlclose(handle);
     }
}
```

and from java code you can call:

```
...
// when you need old .so e.g. in onCreate()
OldSoHelper.loadOldSo();
...

// when you no need to call function from old .so
<TYPE_OF_RESULT> result = OldSoHelper.runFunFromOldSo(<PARAMETERS>);

...
// when you no need old .so e.g. in onDestroy()
OldSoHelper.unloadOldSo();
...
```